# Saving a file to project folder and save its path

Tags: c#

I am using visual studio 2010 (c#).

I would like to select a zip or rar file from my computer, save it to project folder and store its path to a variable.

I tried `openfiledialog()` but I couldn't solve it this way.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             var openFileDialog=new OpenFileDialog {Filter = @"Zip Files|*.zip|RAR Files|*.rar|All Files|*.*"};

            if (DialogResult.OK == openFileDialog.ShowDialog())
            {
                File.Copy(openFileDialog.FileName, Application.StartupPath + @"\" 
                    + Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog.FileName));

                yourvariable = Application.StartupPath + @"\"
                               + Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog.FileName);
            }
        }
```

your file will be copied to yourprojectname\yourprojectname\bin\Debug